# How to execute code from a Ruby GEM I'm building?

Tags: ruby

I'm new in ruby and I'm trying to create a GEM. The "problem" is that I found really hard to execute the code I'm building, without having to repeat a lot of steps. 
This is basically my gem structure

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── Guardfile
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── bin
│   └── hermes
├── hermes.gemspec
├── lib
│   ├── hermes
│   │   ├── code.rb
│   │   ├── issue.rb
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── hermes.rb
├── requirements.md
└── spec
    ├── hermes_spec.rb
    └── spec_helper.rb
```

So I'm running `bundle exec irb`, then `require 'hermes'`and then `Hermes.init`, but if I change any of the files code, I have to exit irb and repeat the steps. Is there a better way of doing it? Which is the "correct" way of doing it (without using rspec) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) and then `load "path/to/file.rb"` every time you change your code. You can also give it a simple web interface with [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) and use [shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun) to have your code reloaded on the fly.

But, the correct way is using rspec. Nothing better than to start fresh and effective employing *test driven development*. Trust me, you'll be ahead of 90% of the market by just starting with tdd from scratch.

Comment: How do you use pry? since I did `bundle exec pry`...load/chage code... `reload!` but I'm getting `NoMethodError: undefined method reload!' for main:Object`. Btw the sinatra option is a good one.

Comment: actually, `reload!` is rails, you can use `load "path/to/file.rb"`. Updating the response